# Regex: pandas.str.contains('binary: [49] ') returns False but in fact, it is True

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

My Pandas string in each row of column `head` starts with `"binary: [49] "` but it returns `False` for

```
all(all(df_ms1[head].str.contains('binary: [49] ')) == True for head in msarray_match)
```

I tested `df_ms1[head].str.contains('binary:'),` it returned `True`. I wonder what is wrong with the word to match `"binary: [49] "`? Is space or number or bracket prohibited here?

Comment: I don't believe you need `== True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are regex metacharacters and have a special meaning.  You must escape them in your pattern if you need literal brackets.

```
all(all(df_ms1[head].str.contains('binary: \[49\] ')) == True for head in msarray_match)
```

By the way, the pattern `binary: [49]` would match either `binary: 4` or `binary: 9`, but not `binary: 49`.

Comment: Why doesn't it match to `binary: 49` but work with single number?

Comment: It would only work for two specific single numbers: 4 and 9.  The quantity `[49]` means match 4 or 9 in regex.  It is not a literal expression.